# Magento2 Upgrade command extension issue

Tags: magento2, module, sql

I am facing an issue while upgrade my custom module from command first time :

```
Error:
Installing schema... SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

For second time upgrade its working fine:

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: check your InstallSchema.php for syntax error

Comment: ok iam checking

Comment: that sql syntax error check your install or upgrade in that module.

Comment: thanks for reply, Can you please more clarify it